# How to target geographic category keywords when pages are for business names

Tags: seo, keywords

I am creating a website similar to Yelp where people come and add their businesses. I noticed that many people use search engines this way: *restaurant in new york*, *auto repair in los angeles*.

But the business page in my website should have a `<title>` that is the name of the business, example: *Mitchell's Ice Cream* or *Luscious Garage*.

What should I make to reach all these search engine users?

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use a `<title>` like this:

```
Mitchell's Ice Cream - restaurant in Los Angeles
```

You just need to add to the `<title>` the category and the city of the business. You can do it easily (getting with PHP or your server language for example) by forcing the user to indicate the category and the city of the business when he creates his page.

This is the best you can do (for `<title>`) for targeting good keywords on Google Search.

Comment: what if the business name doesn't mention the category. like a restaurant with the name "Mamamya", the title would be mamamya in new york

Comment: I have edited my answer.